# Numerical range of a matrix is the closed elliptical disc

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

So, I just read "Matrix Theory: Basic Results and Techniques" by Fuzhen Zhang, and I am stuck on chapter 4. Suppose an $2\times 2$ matrix as follows,
\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

its numerical range $W(A)$ is the closed elliptical disc with foci at $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$, minor axis $1$, and major axis $\sqrt{2}$.

With $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $x$ is a unit complex vector, I got that $x^*Ax=\bar{x_2}(x_1+x_2)$. But, what I don't understand is how is it related to closed elliptical disc?

Could someone explained this in a way an engineering student can relate? Many thanks!